# Javamail Changing Port Number

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Ok i've been trying to put together some code that will read the inbox of a shared mailbox.

I was able to find this code

```
try {
        // create properties field
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "110");
        Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
        emailSession.setDebug(true);

        // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
        Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

        store.connect(host, username, password);

        // create the folder object and open it
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

        for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

        }

        // close the store and folder objects
        emailFolder.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the point that is causing me issues is that even though I've specified port 110 it keeps changing to 995.

Here is the debugging from JavaMail that I get

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.rsetbeforequit: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disabletop: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.forgettopheaders: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.cachewriteto: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.filecache.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.keepmessagecontent: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.starttls.required: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.apop.enable: false
DEBUG POP3: mail.pop3s.disablecapa: false
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "removed", port 995, isSSL true
```

after which i get the following error

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: removed, 995; timeout -1;
```

I've looked at a number of posts and none seem to address this issue and i cannot find a reference to it in the API.

Comment: `mail.pop3.port` is of type `int` so: `properties.put("mail.pop3.port", 110);` see: http://connector.sourceforge.net/doc-files/Properties.html

Comment: I tried that didn't change the port value, still defaulted back to 995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `pop3s` without setting a port for it, so it used the default of 995. See [here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html):

```
mail.pop3.ssl.enable    boolean     If set to true, use SSL to connect and use the SSL port by default. Defaults to false for the "pop3" protocol and true for the "pop3s" protocol.
```

I'll leave it to @BillShannon to tell you how to specify a non-default `pop3s` port.

Or possibly you really meant to use `pop3`?

Comment: What I missed completely, just above the table I cited, and why I deferred to @BillShannon, is the statement that there is another corresponding set of `mail.pop3s.*` properties for `pop3s.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use port 110, the standard pop3 port, why are you using the "pop3s" (pop3 over SSL) protocol instead of the "pop3" protocol?

And if you want to use the standard port, why are you specifying it at all instead of just letting JavaMail use the standard port?

Note also that if you really do want to use the pop3s protocol, setting properties for the pop3 protocol isn't going to have any effect.  You'll want to set "mail.pop3s.*" properties.